# Javascript to open default email client doesn't work

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I need to perform following tasks;

1. on click of link (could be link button, `<a>` or Hyperlink) the default email program at client machine should open up.
2. Javascript for the same has been written as below:

`string adminemail= "xyz@abc.com";    //fetches admin email address; display in To Field`

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updatePanel1, typeof (string), "defaultemail", "window.open('mailto:" + adminemail+ " ');", true);`

But, using the link button is not correct option, as it triggers postback. Hence i thought of using the `<a>` tag, but i am not sure how to link that with the javascript.

How to execute the JS with the help of `<a>` tag? OR Suggest some possible solution for the same.

Please guide!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use [`mailto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)? For example `<a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com">Send email to the admin</a>`

You can also include `cc,bcc,subject` and `body` fields in the query string to customize the email. See the [IANR syntax reference](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html).

Comment: you forgot the `mailto:` part.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it just before you commented :)

Comment: the email address is not fixed. it is coming from database/session

Comment: @Xor power - so why is that a problem? `<a href="<%=...%>">`

Comment: What would be coming under <% %>?

Comment: @Xor - replace the `...` with some server-side variable that holds the email address. I don't know where you're getting it from, but if it's like your original post where you have a variable called `adminemail` then like `<a href="<%=adminemail%>`

Comment: Be aware of the mailto method, there is a character limit and you might experience problems when trying to send emails to a large contact list.

Comment: is there a way to just open the email withour populating it?

Answer (score 0):

An anchor or link button with href/src set to `mailto:` protocol will do fine, e.g:

```
<a href="mailto:[email address]">Mail me</a>
```